# django-Jquery several values transffered to html but one in .js file

Tags: jquery, html, django

I have a next code in html:

```
{% for m in mortgages %}
 <input id ='mortgages_counter' name='mortgages_counter' type='hidden' value='{{ m.MonthlyPaid }}'>
{% endfor %}
```

If I use it for selection menu like:

```
{% for m in mortgages %}
<option value="{{m.MonthlyPaid}}" >{{m.MonthlyPaid }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

I have in selection 2 elements (it is defined by views.py and is a list in its origin)

but if I use it in j query in this way:

```
$( "#mortgages_counter" ).each( function( index, element ){
 console.log( $( this ).val() );
});
```

I see in console only the first value,
And . length also shows 1.

Comment: You can't have more than one element in HTML with the same ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Roseman

deleted id's and used name as a selector for jquery - all works.